# how to get checkbox and textbox value present in a particular row of a table using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get checkbox and textbox value present in a particular row of a table. Below code is working fine in IE7 and not in IE8,9

**HTML**

```
<table id="tblSrc">
   <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="firstrowchkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstrowtxtbox"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="secondrowchkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="secondrowtxtbox"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var tbl = document.getElementById("tblSrc");
var firstrowchkval = tbl.rows[0].cells[0].firstChild.value
var firstrowtxtval = tbl.rows[0].cells[1].firstChild.value
```

How can i get the values using js or jquery by supporting all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ANc3/1/)**

You can use jQuery selectors,

- **[:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** : Retrieves first-child.
- **[:eq(n)](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** : Retrieves nth child.

---

```
$('#tblSrc tr:first input[type="text"]').val();
$('#tblSrc tr:first input[type="checkbox"]').val();
```

to know whether the checkbox is checked or not use ,

```
$('#tblSrc tr:first input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked')
```

Or if you need to get text from specific `<td>`

```
$('#tblSrc tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)').text();
$('#tblSrc tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)').text();
```

Comment: td tr does not have values, input does.

Comment: Yes, right. I edited wrong part of my answer. +1 for the find @MilindAnantwar

Comment: @shaunakde this code $('#tblSrc tr:first input[type="checkbox"]').val(); always returns "on" eventhough it is checked on unchecked.. sorry im new to jquery, how to get checked value

Comment: For checked or unchecked yo need `$('#tblSrc tr:first input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 firstrowchkval = $('#tblSrc tr:eq(0) [type="checkbox"]').val();
 firstrowtxtval = $('#tblSrc tr:eq(0) [type="text"]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.each` to get all the input value

```
$("#tblSrc").find("td input").each(function(){
    alert(this.value)

});
```

or get single value based on `type` selector

```
var catchElement = $("#tblSrc").eq(0);
catchElement.find("[type=text]").val();
catchElement.find("[type=checkbox]").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..
If you want specific row.. then can place eq(1) for 2nd row

```
chkval = $('#tblSrc tr:eq(0) [type="checkbox"]').val();
 txtval = $('#tblSrc tr:eq(0) [type="text"]').val();
```